# How do I merge 3 or more arrays into a single array?

Tags: php, array-merge

How do I merge these arrays?

```
$array1 = array('1' => 'Dog','2' =>'cat');
$array2  = array('1'=>'idly', '2' => 'dosa');
$array3  = array('1'=>'modi', '2'=>'rahul');
```

I want to merge these arrays so my final output is:

```
array(
      '1'=>'dog',
      '2'=>'cat',
      '3'=>'idly',
      '4'=>'dosa',
      '5'=>'modi',
      '6'=>'rahul'
);
```

Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

How about using **[array_merge — Merge one or more arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**:

```
$array1 = array('1'=>'Apple', '2'=>'Banana');
$array2 = array('1'=>'Carrot', '2'=>'Dragon Fruit');
$array3 = array('1'=>'Eggplant', '2'=>'Figs');
$array4 = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
print_r($array4);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Banana
    [2] => Carrot
    [3] => Dragon Fruit
    [4] => Eggplant
    [5] => Figs
)
```